# Splitting strings on two different delimiters

Tags: scala

I have a set of data which looks something like this:

```
1:a:x|y|z
2:b:y|z
3:c:x
4:d:w|x
```

What I want is an output which looks like this:

```
1,a,x
1,a,y
1,a,z
2,b,y
2,b,z
3,c,x
4,d,w
4,d,x
```

I've tried splitting on both ':' and '|' but it didn't help as it gave a result like this:

```
1,a,x,y,z
2,b,y,z
3,c,x
4,d,w,x
```

Also, is there any way I can filter out the unwanted values from the rdd that I get so if I filter out (w,y,z) from

```
1,a,x,y,z
2,b,y,z
3,c,x
4,d,w,x
```

Expected output will be like :

```
1,a,x
2,b,     //it'll be fine if this doesn't even appear, better in fact
3,c,x
4,d,x
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For the second part, you could make a separate question, but the short answer is to use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the only column that can contain several options is the last one

```
rdd.flatMap {
  row => 
   val Array(col1, col2, col3) = row.split(':')
   col3.split('|').map(value => (col1, col2, value) )
}
```

After that you will get an `RDD[(String, String, String)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("1:a:x|y|z"), ("2:b:y|z"),  ("3:c:x"),("4:d:w|x")))
 df.collect
//flat map 
val df1=df.flatMap {
  row => 
   val Array(col1, col2, col3) = row.split(':')
   col3.split('|').map(value => (col1, col2, value) )
}

df1.collect
//filer as per requirments
val df2=df1.toDF("col1","col2","col3")
df2.show()
//df2.createOrReplaceTempView("TempTable")
//val countDF = spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT col1,col2,col3, MIN(col1) FROM TempTable GROUP BY  col1,col2,col3").show()

val w = Window.partitionBy($"col1").orderBy($"col1".desc)

val dfTop = df2.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn").orderBy($"col1".asc)

dfTop.show
```

Results :

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   a|   x|
|   1|   a|   y|
|   1|   a|   z|
|   2|   b|   y|
|   2|   b|   z|
|   3|   c|   x|
|   4|   d|   w|
|   4|   d|   x|
+----+----+----+
```

After filter

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   a|   x|
|   2|   b|   y|
|   3|   c|   x|
|   4|   d|   w|
+----+----+----+

df: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[88] at parallelize at command-4102047427741428:3
df1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[89] at flatMap at command-4102047427741428:6
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string ... 1 more field]
w: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@31cd5345
dfTop: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [col1: string, col2: string ... 1 more field]
Command took 1.01 seconds -- by vaquar.khan@gmail.com at 11/11/2017, 10:35:31 PM on My Cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

First step would be the split for each row:

```
"1:a:x|y|z".split(':').toList.map(_.split('|').toList)

----
in: List[List[String]] = List(List(1), List(a), List(x, y, z))
```

Then generating the combinations:

```
   def combine(input: List[List[String]]): List[List[String]] = input match {
     case x :: xs => x.flatMap(s => combine(xs).map(s :: _))
     case Nil     => List(Nil)
   }

   val res = combine(in).map(_.mkString(","))

   ----
   res: List[String] = List(1,a,x, 1,a,y, 1,a,z)
```

Then you can `.filter` if needed:

```
res.filter(_.contains("x"))
```